How to disable a feature in Feature Manager under Azure App configuration using the Azure SDK
I am building an API to manage features using Azure App Configuration. I saw that it is possible to toggle a feature in the feature manager under Azure App Configuration using the Azure SDK, namely this package Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore.
However, I have written the method below to update a feature flag value given an existing feature name. The code executes successfully. But, in the Azure portal, the feature's value does not reflect the provided value.
public async Task<Result> UpdateFeatureFlag(string featureName, bool isEnabled)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(featureName))
    {
        return Result.Failure(FeatureManagementErrors.InvalidFeatureName());
    }

    try
    {
        var client = new ConfigurationClient(configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig"));
        var isEnabledString = isEnabled.ToString();
        var configurationSetting = await client.SetConfigurationSettingAsync(featureName, isEnabledString);

        if (configurationSetting.Value.Key == featureName && configurationSetting.Value.Value == isEnabledString)
        {
            return Result.Success();
        }

        return Result.Failure(FeatureManagementErrors.FeatureUpdateError(featureName));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = $"FeatureService.UpdateFeatureFlag error: {ex.Message}";
        logger.LogInformation(message);
        return Result.Failure(FeatureManagementErrors.UnexpectedError());
    }
}


Refer this blogs 1 and 2

Yep, that works. The second blog was useful

So thanks to this blog, I was able to get to the answer. This made the difference ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.ff+json;charset=utf-8". My code looks like below
public async Task<Result> UpdateFeatureFlag(string featureName, bool isEnabled)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(featureName))
    {
        return Result.Failure(FeatureManagementErrors.InvalidFeatureName());
    }

    try
    {
        var client = new ConfigurationClient(configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig"));
        var isEnabledString = isEnabled.ToString();
        var featureKey = ".appconfig.featureflag/" + featureName;

        var request = new UpdateFeatureRequest()
        {
            Id = featureName,
            Enabled = isEnabled,
            Conditions = new()
            {
                ClientFilters = new List<ClientFilters>()
                {
                }
            }
        };

        var configurationSetting = new ConfigurationSetting(featureKey, JsonSerializer.Serialize(request))
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.ff+json;charset=utf-8"
        };

        await client.SetConfigurationSettingAsync(configurationSetting);

        await client.SetConfigurationSettingAsync("Settings:Sentinel", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());

        return Result.Success();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = $"FeatureService.UpdateFeatureFlag error: {ex.Message}";
        logger.LogInformation(message);
        return Result.Failure(FeatureManagementErrors.UnexpectedError());
    }
}

